# Neural Network for polynomial fit

Tags: fitting, polynomials, neural-networks

I'm trying to build up a neural network with *Mathematica* 11.0, that should fit data which behaves like a polynom of third order.
I thought that an NN with one or two hidden layers can fit any function, but however in Mathematica the net always performs a linear fit, no matter how many layers und neurons I use.

Has anyone an idea how to build a net for polynomial fit in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 18):

> ... however in Mathematica the net always performs a linear fit, no matter how many layers und neurons I use.

I'm guessing you're using only `DotPlusLayer`s. These are linear - so no matter how many you use, you will always get a linear mapping. To get a nonlinear mapping, you either have to add nonlinear input (e.g. giving the network `x`, `x^2`, `x^3` as input features) or add layers that perform nonlinear operations, like `ElementwiseLayer[Tanh]` or `ElementwiseLayer[LogisticSigmoid]`. For example, this is more or less the standard 1980's style multilayer backpropagation network:

```
net = NetChain[{10, Tanh, 10, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> "Scalar", 
  "Output" -> "Scalar"]
```

The `Tanh` layers are the important part. Now we can train this network:

```
f[x_] := 3*x^3 + 2*x^2 + x
trainingSet = Table[x -> f[x], {x, -1, 1, .01}];

NetInitialize[net];
net = NetTrain[net, trainingSet]
```

And get a decent fit:

```
Plot[{f[x], net[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

The choice of nonlinear element restricts the class of functions the network can fit. For example, if I used `Ramp` instead of `Tanh`, I get a piecewise linear fit:

[image]

Given enough neurons, you will still get a very close fit out of this, but it'll never be a smooth function.

**ADD** as @bills mentioned in a comment, the nonlinear layer also controls the extrapolation behavior, if I pass values outside of the training range to the network: The `Tanh` layer quickly saturates, while the `Ramp` layer continues linearly:

```
Plot[{f[x], net[x], netRamp[x]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", GridLines -> {{-1, 1}, {}}, 
 PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. But it's also instructive to look at the performance of the net outside the training data. You see a pretty interesting plot with `Plot[{f[x], net[x]}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7):

```
f[x_] := 3*x^3 + 2*x^2 + x

t = Table[f[x], {x, -1000, 1000}];

net = NetChain[{10, 10, 1}, "Input" -> 20, "Output" -> "Scalar"]

net = NetTrain[net, Partition[t[[;; -2]], 20, 1] -> t[[21 ;;]], MaxTrainingRounds -> 2]

ListLinePlot[{net@Partition[t[[;; -2]], 20, 1], t[[21 ;;]]}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"net", "orig"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

And now we will show the new data to our network.

```
t = Table[f[x], {x, 1001, 2000}];

ListLinePlot[{net@Partition[t[[;; -2]], 20, 1], t[[21 ;;]]}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"net", "orig"}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Not bad in my opinion.

**UPDATE**

It should be noted that my network is useful for the time series where we have `n` points and are predicting `n+1` point: `{f[x1],f[x2],...,f[x20]}->f[x21], {f[x2],f[x3],...,f[x21]}->f[x22]` etc.

Question is about: `x1 -> f[x1], x2 -> f[x2]` etc.

So @nikie's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: Why does the net get 20 input values? Shouldn't the input be a scalar?

Comment: @nikie It's hard to say what number of input values is right. Of course it can be a scalar. But I have decided that 20 values will be better :-)

Comment: But you're fitting a function from one input to one output. Shouldn't the network take one input and produce one output? How would you evaluate the net for e.g. `x=202.6`?

Comment: @nikie You are right. I cannot evaluate my network if I have only one point. But imagine that we have some financial time series. It's better to show more points to receive more accurate predictions.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake. If clear `f`, then evaluate the `Table` expression and the `Partition` expression, I see `f[...]` on the output *and* the input side. So you're not learning `x -> f[x]`, but `f[x] -> f[x]`, which is a much simpler problem.

Comment: @nikie `{f[x1],f[x2],...,f[x20]}->f[x21], {f[x2],f[x3],...,f[x21]}->f[x22]` etc.

Comment: @nikie I have understood what did you mean under mistake. You are right. This is not simpler problem but this is _different_ problem. I will not change my answer because it also can be useful to someone.

Comment: It's a *linear* problem, and the question was specifically about nonlinear problems, hence my confusion. Anyway, in a real world problem, this would be a perfectly fine solution, so you should definitely leave your answer. Just maybe add a line explaining what it is you're fitting.

Answer (score 7):

Say you have coefficients from several such polynomials, and evaluate on some fixed grid. Suppose also that you want to predict coefficients of unknown cubics, when presented with data values taken from that same grid. Could proceed as below. We start with a random polynomial generator that picks the coefficients from some min/max pair, and uses n+1 values from a regular grid ranging between given low and high x values.

```
randomCubicData[min_, max_, n_, lo_, hi_] := 
 With[{coeffs = 
    RandomReal[{min, max}, 4]}, {Map[Prepend[#, 1] &, 
     Map[#^Range[1, 3] &, Range[lo, hi, (hi - lo)/n]]].coeffs, 
   coeffs}]
```

We'll create 50 of these.

```
SeedRandom[1111];
polys = Table[randomCubicData[-10, 10, 12, -1, 1], {50}];
```

Now we train a table of predictor functions using neural networks, so that each recognizes a specific coefficient.

```
predfuncs = 
  Table[Predict[polys[[All, 1]] -> polys[[All, 2, j]], 
    Method -> "NeuralNetwork", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], {j, 1, 
    4}];
```

We'll test this on a new random set of data values.

```
newpoly = randomCubicData[-10, 10, 12, -1, 1]

(* Out[56]= {{-15.5634949867, -12.6095452135, -10.5331162716, \
-9.13038531929, -8.19752951479, -7.5307260163, -6.92615198204, \
-6.17998457022, -5.08840093906, -3.44757824677, -1.05369365157, 
  2.29707568834, 6.80855261472}, {-6.92615198204, 3.84840149645, 
  2.54868079605, 7.33762230426}} *)
```

Note that the second list gives us the cubic coefficietns we are seeking. We'll see how close the predictors come.

```
Map[#[newpoly[[1]]] &, predfuncs]

(* Out[57]= {-6.98190050885, 4.07123180591, 1.88071818377, 7.32489701602} *)
```

Seems pretty good. I have not tried to test for robustness to noise, nor have I tried to extend to handle varying grids. But this should give an idea at least of how one might use NNs for the task at hand.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers here so far have mentioned ways to do non-linear regression with neural networks. Here is a Polynomial Layer definition that generalizes a LinearLayer element for higher degree polynomials of degree>=1, which can be used to do polynomial regression. The trainable polynomial coefficients are expressed in the Bernstein Basis.

```
polynomialLayer[degree_?IntegerQ, n_ : Automatic, opts___Rule] :=
 NetGraph[
  Join[Table[NetChain[{
      ElementwiseLayer[
       Function[{x}, 
        Evaluate[
         Refine[BernsteinBasis[degree, i, x] // PiecewiseExpand, 
          0 < x < 1 && 0 <= i <= degree]]]]
      ,
      LinearLayer[n, Sequence["Biases" -> None, opts]]
      }], {i, 0, degree}], {TotalLayer[]}]
  ,
  Table[i -> degree + 2, {i, 1, degree + 1}]
  ]
```

The layer is used similarly to a LinearLayer, but with a first argument indicating the degree of the polynomial.

Example:

```
trynet = polynomialLayer[5]
randominput = RandomReal[1, 1000];
randomoutput = #^2 + Exp[Sin[5 #^2]] - 3 # + 1.5 #^5 & /@ randominput;
trainednet = 
 NetTrain[trynet, randominput -> randomoutput, TimeGoal -> Quantity[60, "Seconds"]]

Plot[{trainednet[x], x^2 + Exp[Sin[5 x^2]] - 3 x + 1.5 x^5}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Result]